# Windows 10 BSOD Inaccessible Boot Device -> dism.exe /remove-package -> Files lost in documents folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, bsod

My father in law got the Windows 10 BSOD `Inaccessible Boot Device` error. I tried with the normal `CHKDSK /R` etc but it would not work. I then found this thread:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/inaccessible-boot-device-error-cause-fix/8950ec0c-8502-4af4-aca6-be0e41fe463b

Ran the commands, had the same package as in the example.

```
dir d
dism /Image:D:\ /Get-Packages
dism.exe /image:d:\ /remove-package /packagename:Package_for_KB4014329~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.0
```

The error was still present after this. I then followed the instruction `If you still receive BSOD, rinse and repeat with the next latest update, try it again.`. After removing three updates Windows finally booted normally.

However while his programs where still intact he had lost a lot of files from the `Documents` folder. Could this be due to running `dism.exe`? I first thought he had misplaced them in `OneDrive` but it was empty. I could also find shortcuts that were pointing to files in the `Documents` folder that were now removed.

Is my only option to try and restore these files or can I do something else?

Comment: Inaccessible Boot Device can be sometimes caused by a corrupted registry. Since there are also missing files, I dare say that corruption is probably what you were battling.

Comment: @JerryHundric Any good tip? I’m remoting to the computer so in case I have to recover the files I wan’t minimum file changes to the system.

Comment: Since you ran chkdsk, you'll probably find that all the missing files are in a hidden folder on the root of C drive called found.xxx (where xxx represents some number). As far as I know, nothing in those folders is recoverable.

Comment: Have you tried typing `bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy legacy` at the command prompt?